# issue with application pool reference - IIS Express 7.5

Tags: iis-express

I Have made the application pool entry, virtual directory entry in applicationhost.config file of IIS Express 7.5

Ex:

**Application Pool Entry:**

```
<add name="samples" enable32BitAppOnWin64="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" managedPipelineMode="Integrated">
            <processModel identityType="LocalSystem" />
        </add>
```

**Virtual Directory Entry**

```
<application path="/samplebrowser.Web" applicationPool="samples">
                        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\vel\AppData\Local\Sample\SB.Web" />
    </application>
```

i just click the IIS Express icon in the System tray to browse the sample which has the entry in applicationhost.config file, my sample has not listed there.

If i removed the {applicationPool="samples"} from virtual directory entry, we can see the sample in the system tray. Else i cant.

**My requirement:**
without removing the {applicationPool="samples"} from virtual directory entry, my sample will be listing out in the system tray.

can anyone please help on this?

please give high priority to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IIs Express does not run with application pool identity, instead it runs as current user, so it would not respect processmodel settings.

Try to start iisexpress.exe from command line and check if there is any error during the startup.
To do that, go to IIS Express installation folder and run the following command.

iisexpress.exe /site:"your-site-name" /trace:d